# Jqgrid vertical scrollbar shown internal to the last column in grid and not in scrollbarOffset column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a grid with a subgrid.During the grid initialization my height is set to 'auto' but i am also setting its max-height after initialization so i can have vertical scrollbars if the height is more than '500px'. I dont need horizontal scrollbars and i have defined css rule for it:

```
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
```

The scrollOffset is at its default i.e 18px. However when my grid is expanded to show subgrid the scollbar is visible in the last column instead of showing it in scrollbarOffset column.

In this image below see the scrollbar is inside of last column:

[image: See the scrollbar is inside of last column]

But below it honors the scrollOffset and its outside of last column:

[image]

I want my scrollbar to be in the scrollbarOffset column if the max height has been reached.

Please follow the [test](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9ue/2526/) i created from somebody's test to recreate my problem.

My actual grid is set to 'shrinkToFit' and overflow-x is hidden(which is needed for other purpose). Other than that the fiddle describes my scenario.

Any suggestions or comments are welcomed. Thanks

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
height: 'auto',
colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
colModel: [{
    name: 'id',
    index: 'id',
    width: 60,
    sorttype: "int"},
{
    name: 'thingy',
    index: 'thingy',
    width: 90,
    sorttype: "date"},
{
    name: 'blank',
    index: 'blank',
    width: 30},
{
    name: 'number',
    index: 'number',
    width: 80,
    sorttype: "float"},
{
    name: 'status',
    index: 'status',
    width: 80,
    sorttype: "float"}
],
pager: 'pagerId',
caption: "Stack Overflow Subgrid Example",
subGrid: true,
subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                  "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                  "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                  "reloadOnExpand" : false,
                  "selectOnExpand" : true },
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
    pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
    $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
    $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['No','Item','Qty'],
        colModel: [ {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
                    {name:"item",index:"item",width:130},
                    {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:70,align:"right"}], 
        rowNum:20,
        pager: pager_id,
        sortname: 'num',
        sortorder: "asc", height: '100%' });
     $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

     var subNames = ["num", "item", "qty"];
     var mysubdata = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < subgridData.length; i++) {
        mysubdata[i] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < subgridData[i].length; j++) {
            mysubdata[i][subNames[j]] = subgridData[i][j];
         }
     }
     for (var i = 0; i <= mysubdata.length; i++) {
       $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mysubdata[i]);
     }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm wonder where you get so bad code example! I see the example in many variation many times. It's really bad.

The main problem in the jsfiddle demo: the usage of unneeded CSS rules which are the origin of the problem with scroll bars.

I modified the demo to the following http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/MZ9ue/2529/. It uses input data in the following format:

```js
var mydata = [
    {
        id: 48803, thingy: "DSK1", number: "02200220", status: "OPEN",
        subgridData: [
            {num: 1, item: "Item 1", qty: 3},
            {num: 2, item: "Item 2", qty: 5}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 48769, thingy: "APPR", number: "77733337", status: "ENTERED",
        subgridData: [
            {num: 3, item: "Item 3", qty: 5},
            {num: 2, item: "Item 2", qty: 10}
        ]
    }
];
```

So every row of main data contains information about subgrid data. The code which displays the main grid and the subgrids looks as the following.

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int", key: true},
        { name: 'thingy', width: 90},
        { name: 'number', width: 80, formatter: "integer" },
        { name: 'status', width: 80}
    ],
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    pager: '#pagerId',
    caption: "Stack Overflow Subgrid Example",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridOptions: {
        plusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
        minusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        openicon : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t",
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id,
            localRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", row_id);
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"'></div>");
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: localRowData.subgridData,
            colNames: ['No', 'Item', 'Qty'],
            colModel: [
                { name: "num", width: 80, key: true },
                { name: "item", width: 130 },
                { name: "qty", width: 70, align: "right" }
            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_",
            pager: "#" + pager_id,
            autowidth: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            sortname: "num",
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: "auto"
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id, {edit: false, add: false, del: false});
    }
});
```

It display correctly the data and shows correct example of the usage of jqGrid.

**UPDATED**: If I correctly understand your problem you can do something like on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/MZ9ue/2530/:

I added jqGrid options

```js
shrinkToFit: false,
width: 377,
```

so that the total width of grid will be the sum of widths of all columns plus one have place for the scroll bar. One can set the value dynamically using `setGridWidth` with `shrink` option set to `false`. Then I added the line

```js
$('#grid').closest('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-height", "220px");
```

which set `max-height` on the body div of the grid and finally I added CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

As the result one will have the results

[image]

initially and the following

[image]

after opening subgrids.

**UPDATED 2:** One can don't use `shrinkToFit: false` and `width: 377` option and use the following code instead:

```js
var $bDiv = $('#grid').closest('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv'),
    clientWidth = $bDiv[0].clientWidth, //$bDiv.width(),
    scrollWidth = $bDiv[0].scrollWidth,
    scrollBarWidth = $bDiv[0].scrollWidth - $bDiv[0].clientWidth;

$('#grid').jqGrid("setGridWidth", scrollWidth + scrollBarWidth, false);
```

see one more demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/MZ9ue/2531/

Comment: Hi @Oleg thanks for the answer. I think my question confused you. Let me clarify. I have a grid with initial height set to 'auto' but not more than 500px so i set max-height on .ui-jqgrid-bdiv. However i want to only see the vertical scrollbar but not in the last column of the grid but in the scrollbar offset column. I will update the question with clear info as much as i can. Thanks again

Comment: thanks for the update. I mentioned that i have shrinkToFit option true as i want to resize my grid when browser window is resized. i need shrinkToFit option to be true as a result. Is it also possible to only show scrollbarOffset column when needed otherwise it should be hidden? I have a complex grid with mutliple columns and thus i need to make it as usuable as possible. so when the height is less than max-height i can hide to scrollOffset column and utilize that 18px width for other columns.

Comment: @inputError: Sorry, but I can't full understand your problem. You wrote multiple times about "scrollbarOffset column" which is not exist. Nevertheless I hope I understand now what you need. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/MZ9ue/2531/ and updated part of my answer